# How change GUI.Button/s color at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to archive two things :

1. To be able to change for each individual button he own color in the inspector in runtime.
2. To make a color switch for example when clicking the "LOOP" button change the button color from his current color to another color like a switch between current color and blue. so i know that is loop is true or if loop pressed once make it blue if pressed again switch back to the original color/another color.

This is how the buttons looks like before using the GUI.backgroundColor in the original :
Before using the GUI.backgroundColor in the script :

[image: the buttons with original color]

[image: After changed made using GUI.backgroundColor the color is white transparent ?]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GUIExamples : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture btnTexture;
    public Color color;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!btnTexture)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
        }

        GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 170, 30), "LOOP"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");

        GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 50, 170, 30), "CHANGE DIRECTION"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 90, 170, 30), "PING PONG"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 130, 170, 30), "STOP"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 170, 170, 30), "PAUSE"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");
    }
}
```

Update :

This is what i tried but when i'm changing the color in the inspector in runtime it's not changing the box color :

It will change the color only if i set the color at this line like this :

```
currentStyle.normal.background = MakeTex( 2, 2, new Color( 0f, 1f, 0f, 0.5f ) );
```

But i want to change the color in runtime in real time in the inspector using the color variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GUIExamples : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture btnTexture;
    public Color color;

    private GUIStyle currentStyle = null;
    private Color oldColor;

    private void Start()
    {
        oldColor = color;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!btnTexture)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 170, 30), "LOOP"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 50, 170, 30), "CHANGE DIRECTION"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 90, 170, 30), "PING PONG"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 130, 170, 30), "STOP"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        InitStyles();
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 170, 170, 30), "PAUSE", currentStyle);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 170, 170, 30), "PAUSE"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");       
    }

    private void InitStyles()
    {
        if(oldColor != color)
        {
            currentStyle = null;
        }

        if (currentStyle == null)
        {
            currentStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
            currentStyle.normal.background = MakeTex(2, 2, new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a));

            oldColor = color;
        }
    }

    private Texture2D MakeTex(int width, int height, Color col)
    {
        Color[] pix = new Color[width * height];
        for (int i = 0; i < pix.Length; ++i)
        {
            pix[i] = col;
        }
        Texture2D result = new Texture2D(width, height);
        result.SetPixels(pix);
        result.Apply();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnGUI` is intended for use in editor mode only. Please confirm if you are intending this for in game, or in editor. Also, according to site rules you need to demonstrate what you've tried yourself to solve the problem.

Comment: @Absinthe OnGUI is not for editor only, this use to be the way to write gui in unity (along with GUIText and GUITexture).  To change the look of the ui in OnGUI, you need to create a GUISkin, and modify the button stuff.  Easiest way is to expose a gui skin in your script so you can modify it in the inspector.  Then in the script do, `GUI.skin = mySkin;`  In fact you can have multiple skins, you just need to assign it to GUI.skin before it gets used.

Comment: Working just without changing the alpha.  currentStyle.normal.background = MakeTex(2, 2, new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b));

Comment: I've tried the updated code, and I could see the color of the pause button was changed as expected. If you couldn't see any changes, you might not change the alpha value in the inspector.